# Override referrer Google Analytics with JS or JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, referrer

I am trying to override the referrer of Google Analytics without touching the main Google analytics script or config. The problem is that it is not working. And Google Analytics from what I saw takes the `document.referer` variable, based on my script it does change the `document.referer` variable but still not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        function change_referrer() {
            Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {get : function(){
                var referers = [
                    'twitter.com',
                    'google.com',
                    'facebook.com',
                    'instagram.com'
                ];
                var the_referer = sessionStorage.getItem("the_referer");
                if(!the_referer) {
                    var the_referer = referers.randomElement();
                    sessionStorage.setItem("the_referer", the_referer);
                }
                return the_referer;
            }});
            //ga('set', 'referrer', 'http://'+the_referer);
            console.log(document.referrer);
        }
        change_referrer();
    });
</script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just came across this issue when trying to set iframe's parent URL as a referrer. 
I ended up doing this and it works:

```
gtag('set', {
    referrer: "https://your-referrer-url.com"
})
```